# Using xargs to define custom environment

Tags: environments, optional-arguments, arguments

I want to define a custom environment for the following LaTeX box using `xargs` package, but currently I am running into errors and a bit confused on how to properly make the environment.

First, here's the box in question and then the usage and finally environment:

```
    \newtcblisting[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=examplelist]{tcbexample}[2][]{%
    colback=gray!5, colbacktitle=gray!40, coltitle=black,
    frame hidden, arc=2pt, titlerule=0pt, toptitle=2pt, bottomtitle=2pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, breakable, enhanced, parbox=false,
    comment and listing,
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
    comment={#2},#1
    }
```

Here's an example of the box in use and the source code:

```
\begin{tcbexample}[name = Finding All Occurences, listing options = {language = Python}]
{Use re.findall() to return all instances of a string (text) }
locations = "CA 91105, NY 13078, CA 94702"
re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d\d', locations)
# ['91105', '13078', '94702'] (code)
\end{tcbexample}
```

[image]

This basically follows a pattern of `\begin{tcbexample}[optional arguments, which set name, list type, listing options]{text/comments}code\end{tcbexample}`. I decided to save a bit on the typing by adding a new environment with xargs but it keeps coming up with errors. Here is what I have:

```
\newenvironmentx{example}[2][1={},2={}]{%
    \begin{tcbexample}{#1}{#2}
        }{%
    \end{tcbexample}
}
```

Does anyone know how to correctly make a new custom environment with `xargs`? If so, could you help me figure out what is wrong and how to correct it? Thanks!

Comment: How will the `example` environment save typing? The problem here is that `tcbexample` env will absorb its content in verbatim, hence `\end{tcbexample}` cannot be hidden.

Comment: Well not just save typing, but I guess make the typing more convenient/neater. Thanks for letting me know how it works though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first see what the proposed setup would lead to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newenvironmentx{test}[2][1={abc},2={xyz}]
{Begin \#1=#1, \#2=#2}{End}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Text
\end{test}

\begin{test}[ABC]
Text
\end{test}

\begin{test}[ABC][XYZ]
Text
\end{test}

\begin{test}[][XYZ]
Text
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I therefore guess that you want a similar syntax for your `example` environment:

```
\begin{example}[<tcolorbox options>][<comment>]
```

I'm not sure this would help, because it would force you to add `[]` every time you want a comment:

```
\begin{example}[][some comment]
```

because

```
\begin{example}[some comment]
```

would pass the material in brackets as `<tcolorbox options>`.

Now you can judge whether you want to go along with this strategy.

Next, I'll show you how to dispense with `\newcommandx` which is not supported by `tcolorbox` and use `expl3` for the job.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{ O{abc} O{xyz} }
  {Begin \#1=#1, \#2=#2}
  {End}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Text
\end{test}

\begin{test}[ABC]
Text
\end{test}

\begin{test}[ABC][XYZ]
Text
\end{test}

\begin{test}[][XYZ]
Text
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

You get the same output as before. Note that this is simpler, but very similar to the `xargs` approach: `O{abc}` denotes an optional argument with default value `abc`.

If your LaTeX compiler balks at `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, add `\usepackage{xparse}`.

The good news is that such method is supported by `tcolorbox`. And it allows finer control.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,listings}

\NewTCBListing[
  auto counter,
  number within=section,
  list inside=examplelist,
]{example}{ O{} !o }{
  colback=gray!5,
  colbacktitle=gray!40,
  coltitle=black,
  frame hidden,
  arc=2pt,
  titlerule=0pt,
  toptitle=2pt,
  bottomtitle=2pt,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  parbox=false,
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
  IfValueTF={#2}{comment and listing,comment={#2}}{listing only},
  #1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[%
  listing options = {language = Python}
][Use re.findall() to return all instances of a string (text)]
locations = "CA 91105, NY 13078, CA 94702"
re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d\d', locations)
# ['91105', '13078', '94702'] (code)
\end{example}

\begin{example}[listing options = {language = Python}]
locations = "CA 91105, NY 13078, CA 94702"
re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d\d', locations)
# ['91105', '13078', '94702'] (code)
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that “no comment” also does `listings only`, so you get no dashed line.